# Failed to unlink socket file - mongod

Tags: 14.04, permissions, amazon-ec2, mongodb, aws

Im trying to start mongod. I run "sudo service mongod start", but I get:

```
Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
```

Theres a question here but I have tried all solutions to no avail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813648/failed-to-unlink-socket-file-error-in-mongodb-3-0

When I run "ls -ld /tmp" I see:

```
drwxrwxrwt 3 root root 4096 Jun  1 18:20 /tmp
```

When I run "ls -l /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock" I see:

```
srwx------ 1 mongod mongod 0 Jun  1 18:20 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Mongod needs to be run with sudo, otherwise I get a permissions error. The problem started when I moved the `/var/lib/mongo` folder, then moved it back where it was. Now Mongod wont start.

Im on AWS EC2...

**EDIT**
I've tried:

```
sudo chown mongod:mongod /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Same error.

Tried deleting the file, same error. Tried:

```
# chown root:root /tmp
# chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Same error....

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Remove the temporary socket: `rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`
2. Restart mongo daemon with sudo: `sudo service mongod restart`

Then, the logs announces mongo is initialized and listening on port 27017 and mongo shell can connect.